# Chef - using a ruby script to edit multiple values programmatically

Tags: ruby, scripting, chef-infra, knife

I'm attempting to write a ruby script so I can edit the run_lists of a bunch of nodes resulting from a `knife search` command. I was told to try to use `knife exec`, but I am yielding the same results as I am just executing the script.

I'm using a OS command dictated by the back ticks. The first command works using the `knife search`, but when I feed those results into to the following `each_line` block, it gives me the error in the comments of the script. So, obviously the first part is working, but the second is not even though its setup the exact same way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
#
#

# %CORPCERT% = C:\Users\myuser\Documents\test\knife.rb
# This contains all the pointers to the client.pem, and other required files.

output = `knife search node "fqdn:node*test*.example.net" -i -c %CORPCERT%`

output.each_line do |result|
    #puts result
    puts "Adding run_list to #{result}"
    `knife node run_list add #{result} "role[role_zabbix_agent_corp_prod]" -c %CORPCERT%`
    #puts "#{exitcode}"
end

#C:\U\P028300\Desktop> knife exec apply_run_list.rb -c %CORPCERT%
# => Adding run_list to 8 items found
# => WARNING: No knife configuration file found
# => ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from C:\chef\client.pem
# => Adding run_list to
# => WARNING: No knife configuration file found
# => ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from C:\chef\client.pem
# => Adding run_list to nodeSTtestST0.example.net
# => WARNING: No knife configuration file found
# => ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from C:\chef\client.pem
# => Adding run_list to nodeGWtestST0.example.net
# => WARNING: No knife configuration file found
# => ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from C:\chef\client.pem
# => Adding run_list to nodeGWtestST1.example.net
# => WARNING: No knife configuration file found
# => ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from C:\chef\client.pem
# => Adding run_list to nodeGWtestRT1.example.net
# => WARNING: No knife configuration file found
# => ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from C:\chef\client.pem
# => Adding run_list to nodeGWtestRT2.example.net
# => WARNING: No knife configuration file found
# => ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from C:\chef\client.pem
# => Adding run_list to nodeSTtestRT0.example.net
# => WARNING: No knife configuration file found
# => ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from C:\chef\client.pem
# => Adding run_list to nodeGWtestRT3.example.net
# => WARNING: No knife configuration file found
# => ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from C:\chef\client.pem
# => Adding run_list to nodeGWtestRT0.example.net
# => WARNING: No knife configuration file found
# => ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from C:\chef\client.pem
```

I know I'm not doing the [`knife exec`](https://docs.chef.io/knife_exec.html) command correctly, and the documentation is confusing to me. I haven't found any examples that are close, or related to what I am trying to do. How should I go about trying to programmatically search for nodes, and then update, or add items to their run_list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way of doing this:

```
knife exec -E 'nodes.transform("fqdn:WSO2*") { |n| n.run_list << "role[role_zabbix_agent_corp_prod]" }'
```

`nodes.transform` handles the search loop and the save (as long the block doesn't return nil/false) and `RunList#<<` already checks if it is already in the run list.

Comment: This is definitely what you were telling me to do on IRC, I just didn't understand where to get the items like run_list and such to use in the chef-shell or knife exec. Once I read the articles I linked in my answer, it made sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution is to use [ridley](https://github.com/RiotGames/ridley), a ruby API library for chef server:

```
require 'ridley'

Ridley::Logging.logger.level = Logger.const_get 'ERROR'

ridley = Ridley.from_chef_config("C:\Users\myuser\Documents\test\knife.rb", {:ssl => {:verify => false}})

ridley.search(:node, "fqdn:node*test*.example.net").each { |n|
  n.merge_data(:run_list => ["role[role_zabbix_agent_corp_prod]"])
  n.save
}
```

Comment: While Ridley is very powerful, it is very much overkill for this kind of thing.

Comment: I'll take a look into the Ridley gem still. Good find!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to accomplish what I wanted to do after talking with some friends and IRC chat rooms.

```
# similar to knife search node "fqdn:WSO2*"
search("node", "fqdn:WSO2*").each do |search_node|
    # This looks at the array of the node information, and if the 
    # run_list already exists, do nothing and move on. 
    unless search_node.run_list.include?("role[role_zabbix_agent_corp_prod]")
        # This adds the listed role, or recipe to the end of the run_list
        search_node.run_list.push "role[role_zabbix_agent_corp_prod]"
        # Save the modifications.
        search_node.save
    end #=> End Unless
end #=> End Search
# Make sure to add this to the end, or it will continue to keep running. 
exit 0
```

Put the above script into a file named `script.rb` and run it as such:

```
knife exec script.rb
```

After doing reading through [`knife exec`](https://docs.chef.io/knife_exec.html) and also, [`chef-shell`](https://docs.chef.io/chef_shell.html), I had to play around with the data structures and figure out how they were presented by Chef. The site here: http://www.bonusbits.com/main/Reference:Chef_Node_Data_Structure and http://www.bonusbits.com/main/Reference:Chef_Shell helped a lot as well. I hope this helps someone wanting to understand Chef a bit more.